# How to render ASP.NET's Script Manager followed by the UpdatePanel in webpage on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, mono, asp.net

I wish to find out how to render ASP.NET's Script Manager followed by the UpdatePanel in an webpage on Ubuntu 16.04.

The following aspx script code runs fine on Windows 7 Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 combined with Xamarin Studio.

However, when I request the URL 127.0.0.1:9000/Tutorial.aspx in a Firefox web browser with apache2 and xsp4 running , I encounter the following exception.

System.InvalidOperationException
The control with ID 'UpdatePanel1' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.

```
Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.Extensions.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.get_ScriptManager () <0x41cfa1b0 + 0x0015f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.RegisterPanel () <0x41cfa0b0 + 0x000a7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.OnInit (System.EventArgs e) <0x41cfa050 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive (System.Web.UI.Control namingContainer) <0x41cf9820 + 0x0013c> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive (System.Web.UI.Control namingContainer) <0x41cf9820 + 0x000a4> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive (System.Web.UI.Control namingContainer) <0x41cf9820 + 0x000a4> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.InternalProcessRequest () <0x41cf82d0 + 0x003e1> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) <0x41cea5e0 + 0x001f3> in <filename unknown>:0 
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">    
         <div>
            <div class="container">      
               <div>  
                    <div class="imageFormHead">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, FT_formTitle %>"></asp:Label>
                                    <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>  
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerBC" runat="server" />
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <cc1:TabContainer id="TabControl" runat="server" activetabindex="0" AutoPostBack="True" OnActiveTabChanged="TabControl_ActiveTabChanged">          
                                    </cc1:TabContainer>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Please suggest a solution which enables me to avoid the above exception.

I used this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525525/how-to-add-an-updatepanel-controls-to-a-page-programmatically and I failed to add an update panel control to my test web page programmatically.

```
 System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.Extensions.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.EncryptString (System.String s) <0x418eada0 + 0x00150> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler+RuntimeScriptResourceHandler.System.Web.Handlers.IScriptResourceHandler.GetScriptResourceUrl (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resourceName, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, Boolean zip, Boolean notifyScriptLoaded) <0x418e70a0 + 0x00617> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.GetScriptResourceUrl (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resourceName, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, Boolean zip, Boolean notifyScriptLoaded) <0x418e6f40 + 0x00055> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrlFromName (System.Web.UI.ScriptManager scriptManager, IControl scriptManagerControl, Boolean zip) <0x418e58e0 + 0x000ff> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrl (System.Web.UI.ScriptManager scriptManager, IControl scriptManagerControl, Boolean zip) <0x418e5680 + 0x0012b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts () <0x418e30f0 + 0x0031b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) <0x418e2f00 + 0x000ef> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete (System.EventArgs e) <0x418e2a80 + 0x00090> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessLoadComplete () <0x418c3ce0 + 0x001e0> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.UI.Page.InternalProcessRequest () <0x41876930 + 0x0049f> in <filename unknown>:0
```

[EDIT June 29 2016 7:06P.M] I discovered this evening that a major cause of my problem is that I was mixing apples and oranges. The "apples" being Microsoft's asp:ScriptManager and the "oranges" being Mono's asp:ScriptManager.  Does any expert know why I get this error and  how to fix it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I am running Ubuntu Linux 16.04, I should use Mono's asp::ScriptHandler.  Why would anyone use AjaxToolkitScriptHandler?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348589/difference-between-script-manager-and-toolkit-script-manager where it state that:1. If you using ASP.NET 4.0 (4.5) than you have choice to use ScriptManager or ToolkitScriptManager 2. So, in ASP.NET 4.0 the difference is not so big, and it is better to avoid using ToolkitScriptManager. Thank you.